# How is it possible to draw no-contact crossover edges in Cytoscape?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is there a way to draw crossover edges like the no contact ones on the far right side of this image:

[image: Crossover edge]

It would be useful to disambiguate edge crossings and connections, especially with taxi edges that often link into each other. I realize this would be a non-trivial problem due to identifying those crossovers first and their dynamic natures under interactive manipulation, but it would be very nice to have!

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Would you mind to tell how to realize old style?

Comment: I don't know, it's the same problem as the crossover: you need to identify the intersections to highlight them. So I don't think that's possible out of the box with Cytoscape.